# Using Netbox Ansible Modules

Tags: ansible

I've been wanting to try out Ansible modules available for Netbox [1].

However, I find myself stuck right in the beginning.

Here's what I've tried:

Add prefix/VLAN to netbox [2]:

```
cat setup-vlans.yml 
---
- hosts: netbox 
  
  tasks:
    - name: Create prefix 192.168.10.0/24 in Netbox 
      netbox_prefix:
        netbox_token: "{{ netbox_token }}"
        netbox_url: "{{ netbox_url }}"
        data:
          prefix: 192.168.10.0/24
        state: present
```

That gives me the following error:

```
ansible-playbook setup-vlans.yml 

PLAY [netbox] *********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [NETBOX]

TASK [Create prefix 192.168.10.0/24 in Netbox] ************************************************************************************************
fatal: [NETBOX]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to establish connection to Netbox API"}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************
NETBOX                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Can someone please point me where I am going wrong?

Note: The NetBox URL is an https://url setup with nginx and netbox-docker [3].

Thanks & Regards,
Sana

[1] https://github.com/netbox-community/ansible_modules

[2] https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/netbox_prefix_module.html

[3]
https://github.com/netbox-community/netbox-docker

Comment: The error message tells `Failed to establish connection to Netbox API`. are you able to manually access it using curl ?

Comment: @BaptisteMille-Mathias Yup, I can. `curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Token XXX" https://netbox.url/api/ipam/prefixes/ -H "accept: application/json"
  
{"count":0,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same. Apparently the pynetbox api has changed in instantiation (ssl_verify is now replaced by requests session parameters).

I had to force ansible galaxy to update to the latest netbox module with:

`ansible-galaxy collection install netbox.netbox -f`

The force option did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

All playbooks using API modules like `netbox` (but this is the same for `gcp` or `aws`) must use as host not the target but the host that will execute the playbook to call the API. Most of the time this is `localhost`, but that can be also a dedicated node like a bastion.

You can see in the example on the documentation [you linked](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/netbox_prefix_module.html) that it uses `hosts: localhost`.

Hence I think your playbook should be

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  
  tasks:
    - name: Create prefix 192.168.10.0/24 in Netbox 
      netbox_prefix:
        netbox_token: "{{ netbox_token }}"
        netbox_url: "{{ netbox_url }}"
        data:
          prefix: 192.168.10.0/24
        state: present
```

Comment: Thanks much for pointing that out. I notice that `openssl s_client -connect netbox.url:443 -showcerts 2>&1 | head` gives me `verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate`. That could be the reason it can't connect to the NetBox API, however I don't know how to fix this. I am using a self signed certificate. https://pastebin.com/W5aZi3xs

Comment: Yup sure, I would upvote the answer but since I am a new user, it doesn't allow me yet to upvote. I was wondering if there was a way to specify cacert file with pynetbox, the same way we do with requests with `verify="/my/path/to/cacert.crt"`. https://pastebin.com/zsJNYTSB

Comment: Please create another question, on stackoverflow, one topic = one question.

Comment: Okies, sure. For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62773263/does-pynetbox-api-have-an-option-to-verify-ca-cert-for-self-signed-cert

Comment: Btw, even after adding `validate_certs: false` and using http, I still can't connect to NetBox API. Am I still missing something?

Comment: what is the error message you get, also run the playbook with -vvvv for more verbose output.

Comment: Although I could [connect to NetBox API using python shell](https://pastebin.com/LyLw7svm) I am stuck with using it [with Ansible](https://pastebin.com/6Q99dnBi). Also tried [setting the env variable](https://pastebin.com/vbkvstBP)

Comment: For a problem that you have to target, I suggest rather to go a place for interactive support like IRC chan #ansible. StackOverflow is better for surrounded problem.