# Does PyNetBox API have an option to verify CA cert for Self Signed Cert?

Tags: ansible, python-requests, self-signed-certificate

I've been trying to play around with NetBox Ansible modules with a NetBox setup having self signed certificate. [1] That however gives me the error:

**Failed to establish connection to Netbox API**

I realised that this was due to me using Self signed certificate:

```
>>> import pynetbox
>>> nb = pynetbox.api(
... 'https://netbox.url',
... token='XXX'
... )
 
>>> nb.dcim.devices.all()
 
<snipped>
 
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='netbox.url', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/dcim/devices/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))
```

I was wondering if there is a way to specify cacert file with pynetbox, the same way we do with requests using `verify="/my/path/to/cacert.crt"`

```
>>> nb = pynetbox.api(
... 'https://netbox.url',
... token='XXX',
... private_key_file='/my/path/to/key',
... ssl_verify='/my/path/to/cacert.crt'
... )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_verify'
```

[1] [Using Netbox Ansible Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62768218/using-netbox-ansible-modules/)

Python Version: Python 3.7.7
pynetbox version: '2.8'

Comment: that would be help to edit the question to add which version of python / pynetbox you're using.

Comment: @Baptiste Mille-Mathias Thanks, added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was discussed in [an issue in their GitHub repo](https://github.com/digitalocean/pynetbox/issues/21#issuecomment-352523485) where they allege one can set the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable to point to the CA bundle that `requests` should use for verifying the endpoint [(here are the requests docs)](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/v2.9.1/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)

In theory:

```py
import pynetbox
import os

os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = '/path/to/your/ca.pem'
# and off to the races
```

Comment: Thanks much @mdaniel. That helped. https://pastebin.com/LyLw7svm

Answer (score 2):

You can disable ssl verification like so:

```
nb.http_session.verify = False
```

It's mentioned in the docs here https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pynetbox/latest/pynetbox.pdf